# How to collect the data of the HTMLParser in Python 3

Tags: html, python-3.x, html-parsing

Dears,

I need to collect the Data in the below HTML in a array of string

```
parser.feed( <table><tr><td><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JX1ZS5O" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41B39oDSGQL._SL160_.jpg" alt="Product Image" style='border:0'/></a></td><td><tr><td>List Price: <strike>$34.99</strike></td></tr><tr><td><b>Deal Price: $7.99</b></td></tr><tr><td>You Save: $2.00 (20%)</td></tr><tr><td>Sabrent 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub with Individual Power Switches and LEDs (HB-UM43)</td></tr><tr><td>Expires Jun 15, 2017</td></tr></td></tr></table>)
```

so I used the below but

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.Datacollected(data)
        return (data)
parser = MyHTMLParser() 
Collector=[]
Collector.append[parser.feed("HTML Code HERE")]
```

but it is Always Empty

Answer (score 1):

The `feed` method is parsing one HTML element at a time, and handing it over to the `handle_data` method. The return value of [feed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/html/parser.py#L104) is `None`, that's why your list is empty. If you want to keep all the data fed into the parser, you need to add some data structure in the `__init__()` method, like a `list`, include the data into it within the `handle_data` method, and implement another method that returns your data, e.g.:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs, *args):
        self.d = []
        super().__init__()

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.d.append(data)
        return (data)

    def return_data(self):
        return self.d

collector=[] 
parser = MyHTMLParser() 
parser.feed("HTML Code HERE")
collector.append(parser.return_data())
```